# Yii2 Gridview URL too long

Tags: gridview, yii2, filtering

I have a Gridview with a lot of columns and the class has a particularly long name (`MapInvestorToCountryRankDataProvidor`). Whenever a user filters the Grid a very long URL is generated.

Is there a way to use an alias for the Class Name rather than the whole class?

Comment: are you talking about the model name like `ModelName[field]` that is appended to the url  as query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [formName](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#formName()-detail) method inside  your search model that you are using for the GridView

Add the function like below in your model and it will be used instead of that name

```
public function formName()
{
    return 'smallName';
}
```

**Note: You can even return the empty string if you dont want the model name to be appended at all.**

Comment: happy to help @DrBorrow